# node-expat compiled on windows but module not found

Tags: windows, node.js, node-gyp

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-expat/tree/gyp and node-gyp were used to compile it. node_expat.node was generated. I get the follow error when reference in code:

```
module.js:485
  process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
          ^
Error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\Users\s\Desktop\Translink\TooTallNate-node-expat-e7d7cb5\build\Releas
\node_expat.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\s\Desktop\Translink\server.js:1:181)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

I couldn't get further trying to get node-expat on windows. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs the libexpat.dll as .node is actually a dynamic linked library. I copied the libexpat.dll in to the Release directory to make it work. It could be copied into system32 as well.

Comment: you will need to install expat for windows here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/

Comment: This should not be necessary. libexpat get statically linked to the compiled `.node` file. If you needed a `.dll` file of any kind than something is not right.